# How to represent an integer $N$ as $x^a y^b$

Tags: exponentiation, perfect-powers

Is there a fast way to find a representation of an integer $N$ of an arbitrary length as $x^a y^b$ ?

I thought I could find it quickly using some kind of log operations, but I can't come up with a solution.

For example: let's say we want to find such representation for $N = 1944$.
The answer would be $1944 = 3^5  2^3$.

What is the algorithm to find $x^a y^b$ for, let's say, $N = 73625$?

Ideally, I would want it to be in a compact form, hence: $a,b,x,y<999$.

Comment: What sort of representation do you want? There's always trivial ones, like $x = N, y = a = b = 1$.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Suppose $N=30=2\times 3\times 5$. How would you write that as $x^a\,y^b$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've added an example. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Not really.  Most numbers don't have such a simple expression.  $73625=5^3\times 19\times 31$ for example.

Comment: Are you aware of the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)?

Comment: @RobArthan yes, but, I'm not sure how it relates to the question, I'm not good at math

Comment: Basically the answer your looking for is no. there is no fast way because theirs isnt a way alot of the time, if there was it would true that every integer is simply the product of 2 primes/ composites to some power which is obviously false... see lulu's examples.

Comment: @lulu so it means that even if 40297104 can be represented as $23^4 * 12^2$, there's probably no way to represent 40297105 in a similar way? What if we had 3 variables, would it make it more plausible to find the representation for any other number?

Comment: That is correct.  That number is $5\times 1321 \times 6101 $ for what it's worth.  These numbers are all quite small, wolfram alpha can factor them easily.

Comment: To be (slightly) more complete, about $60\%$ of the natural numbers are square free...hence will be the product of distinct primes.

Comment: @lulu sorry, does it mean 60% of integers can be represented as product of 2 primes to some power?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic tells you that you can factor any number $N$ into a product of prime powers in a unique way. From that factorisation you can calculate all the possible ways of writing $N$ as $x^ay^b$. But now you need to tell us about any other constraints you want to impose on $x$, $a$, $y$ and $b$.

Comment: No.  That means that roughly $60\%$ of integers have no powers in them.  Like $30=2\times 3\times 5$ they are just the product of distinct prime numbers.

Comment: @Un1:Are you excluding  $73625 = 5^1 \cdot 14725^1$? If so, please explain exactly what constraints you are imposing. A single example does **not** make things clear.

Comment: @lulu: you are reading into the OP's question the assumption that $x$ and $y$ are prime. The OP hasn't said that.

Comment: @RobArthan ideally I want it to be $a,b,x,y < 99$ to make it compact, but I guess it's not possible for any integer I want

Comment: @RobArthan  Not at all...I am, however, assuming that the OP wants $a,b>1$ else the problem is trivial.  Well, it's trivial if $N=N^1\times 1^1$ is allowed.  Less trivial if a single proper factor is called for.

Comment: @lulu: fair enough. I think we've probably both wasted enough time on this ill-defined question.

Comment: @RobArthan  Agreed.

Comment: "The answer would be $1944=3^52^3$"  Those aren't the only. $3^2*6^3$ is another one.  But must numbers won't $1943=29*67$ can not.  And $1945 =5*389$ can not.  All prime factors have at least 2 power.  And if there is only one prime factor it must be at 4 power.

Comment: $73625= 5^3*19*31$.  Can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob and lulu basically answered it in the comments.

1) Find the prime factorization of $N = p_1^{n_1}*p_2^{n_2}.....*p_m^{n_m}$

2) If any of the $n_i$ are equal to one it can not be done.  This will happen about $60\%$ of the time!

3) If you only have two prime you are done: $N = p_1^{n_1}*p_2^{n_2}$.

4) If you have only one prime less than or equal to $3$ i.e. $N= p^3$ or $p^2$ it can not be done but other wise you are done: $N = p^n = p^a*p^b$ for any $a+b=n$.

5) If all then $n_i$ are even then you are done $N=(p_1)^{n_1}*(p_2^{n_2/2}*....p_m^{n_m/2})^2$.

6) Separate the even $n_i$ from the odd from the odd so that

$N = p_l^{2k_l}...p_j^{2k_j}*p_h^{2k_h + 3}...p_i^{2k_n + 3}$

7)  Break this into $N = (p_1^{k_1}..... p_n^{k_n})^2*(p_h....p_i)^3$.

8) The only case not covered  above  is if $N= p_1^3.....p_n^3$.  In this case $N = (p_1)^3*(p_2.....p_3)^3$.

So for example, if I take  $N=16810159716000$

Prime factorization is $N=2^5 * 3^6 * 5^3 * 7^8$

$= (2^2*3^6*7^8)*(2^3*5^3) = (2*3^3*7^4)^2*(2*5)^3 = 129654^2*10^3$

Which is  not the *only* way to do it. Ex. $(2*7)^2(2*3^2*5*7^2)^3$ will also work.  It's just a matter of splitting the prime factors so that all the exponents are all multiples of one of two numbers.  Which sounds hard but is easy to do in practice.  That is if it can be done at all,  Which it usually won't, but will be easy to see when it can't.

Comment: thanks for breaking it down